# Accessing Multiple FBO Textures in GLSL to create another texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, fbo

I created 4 textures and attach them to FBO, named fbo_texture0 - fbo_texture3. All of them are successfully created, as given by the following screenshot:

[image: Textures in the FBO]
*image 1*

Now, i wanted to create the 5th texture which is obtained from the previous textures (fbo_texture0 - fbo_texture3) using GLSL. For now, i just want to copy the first texture into the fifth texture. Unfortunately, here is what i got:

[image: texture fail]
*image 2*

The question is:

1. How can i access these fbo textures in GLSL?
2. How can i create the 5th texture? (or copy from the first texture to the fifth texture?)

Here's the complete code of the program (in case needed):

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h> // Include the GLEW header file
#include <GL/glut.h> // Include the GLUT header file
#include <iostream> // Allow us to print to the console

using namespace std;

bool* keyStates = new bool[256]; // Create an array of boolean values of length 256 (0-255)

unsigned int fbo; // The frame buffer object
unsigned int fbo_depth; // The depth buffer for the frame buffer object
unsigned int fbo_texture0; // The texture object to write our frame buffer object to
unsigned int fbo_texture1;
unsigned int fbo_texture2;
unsigned int fbo_texture3;
unsigned int fbo_texture4;
GLhandleARB shaderProgram;
GLhandleARB vertexShader;
GLhandleARB fragmentShader;

int window_width = 500; // The width of our window
int window_height = 500; // The height of our window

void initFrameBufferDepthBuffer(void) {
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &fbo_depth); // Generate one render buffer and store the ID in fbo_depth
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fbo_depth); // Bind the fbo_depth render buffer
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, window_width, window_height); // Set the render buffer storage to be a depth component, with a width and height of the window
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); // Unbind the render buffer
}

void initFrameBufferTextures(void) {
    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture0); // Generate one ture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture0); // Bind the ture fbo_texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); // Create a standard ture with the width and height of our window
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture1); // Generate one ture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture1); // Bind the ture fbo_texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); // Create a standard ture with the width and height of our window
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture2); // Generate one ture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2); // Bind the ture fbo_texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); // Create a standard ture with the width and height of our window
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture3); // Generate one ture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture3); // Bind the ture fbo_texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); // Create a standard ture with the width and height of our window
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture4); // Generate one ture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture4); // Bind the ture fbo_texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); // Create a standard ture with the width and height of our window
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void printInfoLog(GLhandleARB obj)
{
    int infologLength = 0;
    int charsWritten  = 0;
    char* infoLog;

    glGetObjectParameterivARB(obj, GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, &infologLength);
    if (infologLength > 0)
    {
        infoLog = (char*)malloc(infologLength);
        glGetInfoLogARB(obj, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
        printf("%s\n",infoLog);
        free(infoLog);
    }
}

void initFrameBuffer(void) {
    initFrameBufferDepthBuffer(); // Initialize our frame buffer depth buffer
    initFrameBufferTextures(); // Initialize our frame buffer ture
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo); // Generate one frame buffer and store the ID in fbo
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); // Bind our frame buffer
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture0, 0);// Attach the ture fbo_texturen to the color buffer in our frame buffer
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture1, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2, 0); 
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture3, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture4, 0);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, fbo_depth); // Attach the depth buffer fbo_depth to our frame buffer
        GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); // Check that status of our generated frame buffer
        if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) // If the frame buffer does not report back as complete
        {
            cout << "Couldn't create frame buffer" << endl; // Output an error to the console
            exit(0); // Exit the application
        }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // Unbind our frame buffer
}

void init(void) {
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable turing so we can bind our frame buffer ture
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing
    initFrameBuffer(); // Create our frame buffer object
}

void keyOperations (void) {
    if (keyStates['a']) { // If the a key has been pressed
        // Perform 'a' key operations
    }
}

void renderTextures(void) {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); // Bind our frame buffer for rendering
    glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT); // Push our glEnable and glViewport states
    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height); // Set the size of the frame buffer view port

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the clear colour
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Clear the depth and colour buffers
        glLoadIdentity();// Reset the modelview matrix
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
       //Add ambient light
        GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f}; //Color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
        glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);

        //Add positioned light
        GLfloat lightColor0[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        GLfloat lightPos0[] = {4.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 1.0f}; //Positioned at (4, 0, 8)
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);
        //Add directed light
        GLfloat lightColor1[] = {0.5f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.5, 0.2, 0.2)
        //Coming from the direction (-1, 0.5, 0.5)
        GLfloat lightPos1[] = {-1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f};
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor1);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPos1);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glutSolidTeapot(2.0);
        glColor3f(0.1,0.2,0.7);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the clear colour
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Clear the depth and colour buffers
        glLoadIdentity();// Reset the modelview matrix
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
        glutSolidTorus(0.80, 1.6, 50, 100);
        glColorMaterial ( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION ) ;
        glEnable ( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL ) ;

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set the clear colour
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Clear the depth and colour buffers
        glLoadIdentity();// Reset the modelview matrix
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
        glutSolidTetrahedron();
        glColorMaterial ( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION ) ;
        glEnable ( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL ) ;

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3);
        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f); // Set the clear colour
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Clear the depth and colour buffers
        glLoadIdentity();// Reset the modelview matrix
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
        glutSolidOctahedron();
        glColorMaterial ( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION ) ;
        glEnable ( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL ) ;

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // Unbind our ture

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture0);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex0"), 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture1);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex1"), 1);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex2"), 2);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture3);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex3"), 3);

glPopAttrib(); // Restore our glEnable and glViewport states
glutSwapBuffers();
}

static char* textFileRead(const char *fileName) {
    char* text;

    if (fileName != NULL) {
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rt");

        if (file != NULL) {
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
            int count = ftell(file);
            rewind(file);

            if (count > 0) {
                text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
                count = fread(text, sizeof(char), count, file);
                text[count] = '\0';
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return text;
}

void initShader(){
    char* vsSource = textFileRead("./shader/multitexture.vs");
    char* fsSource = textFileRead("./shader/multitexture.fs");

    printf("%s\n",fsSource);

    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar **)(&vsSource), NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    printInfoLog(vertexShader);

    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar **)(&fsSource), NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    printInfoLog(fragmentShader);

    delete [] vsSource;
    delete [] fsSource;

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
}



void display (void) {
    keyOperations(); // Perform any key presses
            glUseProgram(0);
    renderTextures(); // Render our teapot scene into our frame buffer
            GLsync s = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
            glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Clear the background of our window to red
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colour buffer (more buffers later on)
    glLoadIdentity(); // Load the Identity Matrix to reset our drawing locations
    glTranslatef(-4.7f, 1.0f, -4.0f);

    glWaitSync(s, 0, GL_TIMEOUT_IGNORED); 
        glDeleteSync(s);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture0); // Bind our frame buffer ture
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind any tures

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-2.5f, 1.0f, -4.0f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture1); // Bind our frame buffer ture
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
        glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind any tures

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-0.3f, 1.0f, -4.0f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture2); // Bind our frame buffer ture
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind any tures

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(1.9f, 1.0f, -4.0f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture3); // Bind our frame buffer ture
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind any tures

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(4.1f, 1.0f, -4.0f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture4); // Bind our frame buffer ture
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind any tures

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape (int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height); // Set our viewport to the size of our window
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Switch to the projection matrix so that we can manipulate how our scene is viewed
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset the projection matrix to the identity matrix so that we don't get any artifacts (cleaning up)
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 100.0); // Set the Field of view angle (in degrees), the aspect ratio of our window, and the new and far planes
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Switch back to the model view matrix, so that we can start drawing shapes correctly
}

void keyPressed (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = true; // Set the state of the current key to pressed
}

void keyUp (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    keyStates[key] = false; // Set the state of the current key to not pressed
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGBA); // Set up a basic display buffer (only single buffered for now)
    glutInitWindowSize (1280, 500); // Set the width and height of the window
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100); // Set the position of the window
    glutCreateWindow ("OpenGL FBO"); // Set the title for the window

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    initShader();
    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display); // Tell GLUT to use the method "display" for rendering
    glutIdleFunc(display); // Tell GLUT to use the method "display" for rendering
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); // Tell GLUT to use the method "reshape" for reshaping
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed); // Tell GLUT to use the method "keyPressed" for key presses
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp); // Tell GLUT to use the method "keyUp" for key up events
    glutMainLoop(); // Enter GLUT's main loop
}
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
void main(void) 
{ 
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

And here is the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
uniform sampler2D tex3;

void main(void) 
{ 
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

**EDIT #1**

After modifying the code as suggested by @Damon (the code has been edited as well) , here's the screenshot of the result:

[image]
*image 3*

Now, I don't really know what the problem actually is. I tried to change the fragment shader to access another texture e.g. `gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex2, gl_TexCoord[0].st);` but i still got the same display as above. So i think it is definitely not the modelview/projection problem.

**EDIT #2**

The problem still left unclear. However, I tried to give only one `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREn);` command at the program,  and comment out other `glActiveTexture` command (without shader modification), and got the following result:

[image]
*image 4* Only `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);`activated.

[image]
*image 5* Only `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);`activated.

[image]
*image 6* Only `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);`activated.

[image]
*image 7* Only `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);`activated.

When at least 2 `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREn);` activated, i got the same result as *image 5*. That left me wondering what the problem actually is.

Comment: Have you found the cause of your problem? I have the same exact issue and I'm really becoming crazy..

Comment: unfortunately no. i'm sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 3):

`initShader` compiles and links a shader. You seem to be binding the textures to texture units within `renderTextures` in an OK manner, too (after unbinding the FBO, which is important to sync). So far so good, but I can't find `glUseProgram` anywhere in the code. That would mean the rendering falls back to fixed function, which does not have any textures bound at that time.

The fragment shader reads only from tex0, so of course you wouldn't expect to see tex1-tex3 anyway (but I guess that's just the minimum working example code).

Other than that, it looks OK from what I can see by reading over the code in 5 mins.

(As a sidenote: `init` calls `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, this is not strictly wrong, but useless as soon as you use a shader, see [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_%3a_common_mistakes#Enable_Or_Not_To_Enable).)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your time. By not using glUseProgram is a foolish mistake by the way.So i made revision on the code by commenting on the glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and use glUseProgram(shaderProgram) on the display() method. However, i got the same result (all black on texture), and got some warnings: 
"warning <#332> gl_TexCoord is only available in compatibility profile" and "warning <#332> gl_MultiTexCoord0 is only available in compatibility profile". Is there any way i can fix the shader script?

Comment: In your edited code, you activate your shader program (`glUseProgram`) _before_ `renderTextures()`. It only makes sense to activate it _after_ that (in fact, one should probably `glUseProgram(0)`), since it uses textures as input which are neither defined yet nor bound at that time. About the compatibility warning, the "correct" way is to use generic vertex attributes, but since you certainly have a compatibility context (using fixed function all over the place!), it should be ok. You should neverthelesss place a `#version 150 compatibility` in your shader code to remove any doubts.

Comment: The warning no longer exist when i remove the `#version 150` line . Thank you. However, the result is still the same with all black textures displayed when i move `glUseProgram(shaderProgram)` _after_ renderTextures() method. When i use `glUseProgram(0)`, the textures turns to white. Probably, the mistake lies on how i access the texture in the shader?

Comment: Re:`glUseProgram(0)` I meant to use that _before_ you draw the geometry, in addition to `glUseProgram(shaderProgram)` afterwards. Since `display` will be called many times, you cannot just assume that no shader is bound (this is only true the first time). You want to draw your teapots without shader. About the texture access, I can't see anything wrong. The shader accesses `tex0` which is bound (lines 190-193) to texture unit 0, which refers to `fbo_texture0`. (The state changes when you render your teapots are a bit weird, but you said this works, so let's ignore that.)

Comment: The only other possible cause that I see apart from not properly enabling/disabling the shader would be a synchronisation issue, that is reading the texture before the GPU has finished drawing to it. But I don't really believe that this is what happens. First, you _do_ unbind the FBO before binding textures, which should properly sync (and the one being read is the first one rendered, too), and second, if there was a sync issue, one would expect at least some half-drawn frames sometimes, not just a consistently black screen.

Comment: After editing the code as you have suggested, I got a bit progress, that is a bit fragment drawn (as seen from the screenshot above, on the **edit** section). So maybe this is a sync issue. But i don't have any idea how to fix this either.

Comment: Now this *does* look like a sync issue, though I don't understand why. Oh well... since you are using GLSL 1.5, you have OpenGL 3.2, so ARB_sync must be present, it's worth a try: insert `GLsync s = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);` after line 266 (where you call `renderTextures()`) and `glWaitSync(s, 0, GL_TIMEOUT_IGNORED); glDeleteSync(s);` before line 274. This will force block before using the texture until all render commands prior to the `glFenceSync` call are realized. Hopefully that fixes it (there should be a cleaner way too, though).

Comment: a bit more complicated, thank you for staying with me. I have edited the code (as shown above) and yet i still have the result as shown in the `edit` section.

Comment: Well, if the fence didn't change anything, it is not a sync issue (unbinding the FBO should have been good enough anyway, but the fence made it 110% good). So, it draws ok, the texture is bound ok, it's properly synced, and yet it does not show anything. Which leaves me a bit clueless... :(

Comment: Yeah.. me too. I did a bit experiment by commenting out some `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREn);` and left only one `glActiveTexture()` activated, and a got some screenshot as in **Edit #2** section.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); // Bind our frame buffer for rendering
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture0); // bind texture that is rendered in 0-th attachment
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
glEnd();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

You just render into 4th attachment with binded texture from 0-th attachment.